# Impossible to extend second HDMI monitor in Ubuntu 22.04 (same in Winows 11)

Tags: hdmi

I have two HDMI monitors connected to my laptop using an HDMI splitter. In Ubuntu 22.04 I only can see one of them, and the other one is working in Ubuntu, but only as a mirror or the first one (I cannot extend the monitor)[image]

In this screenshot you can see two, one is the first HDMI monitor, and the second is the laptop screen (but there is not any second HDMI monitor, why?).

Note: I think the problem is not in Ubuntu, it is in the HDMI splitter I am using. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: A splitter takes one output to two monitor but for the computer is only one, obviously. It's neither a problem with the OS or splitter, it's a problem of not understanding what the splitter is.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think an HDMI splitter is going to do what you want. It doesn't magically add a 3rd screen; it just doubles 1 screen.

You need to find a way to attach a 3rd screen to the computer. Either use the VGA port, or a Displayport if you have one, or attach a docking station with more ports, or in desperation use a USB display controller.